# watch command not working with special characters and quotes

Tags: bash, awk, pipe, watch, nvidia-smi

```
watch -n 1 "paste <(ssh ai02 'nvidia-smi pmon -s um -c 1') <(ssh ai03 'nvidia-smi pmon -s um -c 1' )"
```

The above command is used to horizontally stack two server GPU stats together. It works without the watch command but get the following error

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `paste <(ssh ai02 'nvidia-smi pmon -s um -c 1') <(ssh ai03 'nvidia-smi pmon -s um -c 1' )'
```

Comment: Btw.: `sh` != `bash`

Comment: It's a recurrent problem of shell expansion and quoting.

Comment: Follow Cyrus and Ronaldo, so, put your command line `paste <(ssh ai02 'nvidia-smi pmon -s um -c 1') <(ssh ai03 'nvidia-smi pmon -s um -c 1' )` in a bash shell script (with a bash  shebang) and execute it with the `watch` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a reproducible example, but I think I managed to make one for testing:

```
watch -n1 "paste <(seq -w 1000 | shuf -n '10' ) <(seq -w 1000 | shuf -n '10')"
```

output a similar error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `paste <(seq -w 1000 | shuf -n '10' ) <(seq -w 1000 | shuf -n '1
0')'
```

To solve this problem in a simpler way, we can change `sh -c` for `bash -c`:

```
watch -n1 -x bash -c 'paste <(seq -w 1000 | shuf -n "10" ) <(seq -w 1000 | shuf -n "10")'
```

From the `watch` manual:

```
-x, --exec
     Pass command  to exec(2) instead of  sh -c which reduces  the need to
     use extra quoting to get the desired effect.
```

If you need maintain the apostrophes from the original commandline, you can escape then too:

```
watch -e -n1 -x bash -c 'paste <(seq -w 1000 | shuf -n '\''10'\'' ) <(seq -w 1000 | shuf -n '\''10'\'')'
```